# Can't get grid elements in rows vertically aligned

Tags: bootstrap-5

I can't get controls aligned in two rows with different amount of elements.

[image: capture]

Can't find the way to get the right side of the select vertically aligned with the right side of the button.
My code:

```
<div class="container text-center col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-3">
        <div class="col-10">
            <div id="reportrange">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the button didn't have enough space (it was overflowing to the right). If you change `col-10` and `col-2` to `col-9` and `col-3`, everything works fine.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container text-center col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-9">
      <div id="reportrange">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```